# Why was the VaadinOSGIApplicationManager changed to An Activator in org.vaadin.osgi

Tags: osgi, vaadin

org.vaadin.osgi_1.0.1.jar uses declarative services in the VaadinOSGIApplicationManager class.

Later versions on github now use an Activator in place of the ApplicationManager.

Is the change done for bndtools v2 purposes or for other reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Declarative services are not installed in every OSGi framework. So I think using the Activator makes it run on a bigger variety of platforms out of the box.